# Help in Algebra 2 home assignment , Bases .

Tags: linear-algebra

$B=\{1+x,1-x,x^3+x^2,x^2-x^3\}$    $V=P_3[x]$

I need to prove that if $[p(x)]_B\neq0$ so $\forall 0 \neq v \in \mathbb{R}^4 $ there is a base $S$ of $V$ that Uphold $[p(x)]_S=v$.

please if you know the answer i would like to see the full algebraic way 
so i can understand (My English isn't the best):)

Comment: Are you sure that $B$ contains $x^2+x^3$ twice? What is Uphold of $p(x)$?

Comment: You are right I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that every element of $B$ can be expressed as a linear combination of your basis.  If you already know a basis of $P_3[x]$, say $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\},$ one way to show it is to show you can express these four in terms of your basis elements.  Then since everything is linear you can express all of $B$ in your basis.

Comment: I fixed the question sorry for the error

Comment: OK, my approach works now.